# How can I change the text of a label while running in visual basic?

Tags: label, basic

Right now my label is having a text "hello", how can I change it to "world" by a button click while running in Visual Basic.

Comment: You have to write code to change the Text property to the value you want.  This question appears not to be on topic since it appears to be a programming question.

Comment: Welcome to SU, Sabarish! Please take a look: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Sabarish. Programming questions should go onto [so] rather than Super User. Also, it's best to describe what steps you have taken to try to solve the problem yourself; we are a question and answer site, not a free consultant site.

Answer (score 2):

Write a button click event. It can be done either manually or by double clocking on the button in the designer view:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

End If
```

Notice the end of it how it says "Button1.Click". Change Button1 to whatever the name of your button is.

Now add the code to change your textbox's text:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Textbox1.text = "world"
End If
```

Again note the name of the textbox and change "Textbox1" to whatever your textbox is named.

I assume you are new to learning how to program since what you asked is pretty basic. Try to find some tutorials online to help you better understand things. In this case you should look up and understand how control properties work along with events.